# ExpandableListview is not showing fully

Tags: android, android-layout

The bottom part of the screen does not display rows even though they are loaded. When scrolled up, the rows move to the top  and when invalidated the adapter, the application works fine by displaying the full screen.

Here is the layout am using.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/homescreenview"
android:orientation="vertical" 
>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/homescreenmainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/internetstatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#912E3D">

 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/interneticon"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/nonetwork" 
            />

<TextView 
            android:id="@+id/internetstatustext"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/interneticon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/nonetconnection"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            />

</LinearLayout>

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
    </ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Please find attached screenshot.

[image: Here leaving empty screen at bottom of screen.]

Comment: i guess you used 3 linear layout,but close only 2,didn't close the parent linear layout

Comment: @Venu. That is not an issue, I forgot to close when am posting. Thanks for viewing my post.

Comment: You want 3 layouts, one header, one footer and fill the rest with the list, am I  right?

Comment: then you can take the help of this. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Header and footer are different thing here. Just I want fill with list. It is working as expecting, but in rare cases it is leaving empty screen at bottom. Thanks for viewing my post -  Carlos Verdes

Answer (score 0):

there is a trick to fill all the space in the screen, try this and let me know, you should set the height of your listview to 0dp and weigth to 1... Android will calculate height automatically for you.

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Comment: @NightSkyLove with this kind of detailed comment... it's complicated to answer. By the way it's been some time since I haven't develop with Android so maybe this solution is not needed or is implemented with a different approach nowadays, I recommend you to raise another question.

Comment: Applying a weight basically did nothing for me. I had an issue where I was adding an ExpandableListView however, only the first item in the ExpandableListView would show up. Not the other 6 which I had. Still not sure why it isn't working for me.

Comment: I think is better if you open a question in SOF with example of your code, maybe your problem is where did you put the attribute (in which html element)